# Access to macroblocks and motion values with libx264

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libx264

I have a question and I hope someone can help me.
I want to extract all motion vectors in P_type mocroblock  in a P_frame  during encoding 
h264 video with libx264 (x264). libx264 uses X264Context in the function x264_frame to encode
video. Then, I want to know how can I access to  macroblocks in a picture and 
how to access to motion vectors table on this picture while using the X264Context struct.
With MpegEncContext we can access them while using MpegEncContext struct's mb_type, *mvs[2], mb_width, mb_height and mb_stride. But I don't know how to have such informations ( 
mb_type, *mvs[2], mb_width, mb_height and mb_stride) with X264Context struct.

Please I need your help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with libx264 because it doesn't provide API to get this information (MVs) from it.

Comment: Ok. But I want to know if there is an encoder on ffmpeg used to encode h264 format? Enlight me please.